# How to show Window and command-line prompt?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a way to show a Window and CMD in combination? I would like to use the cmd as a debugging info logger in my Window application.

Comment: Maybe [try this](http://dslweb.nwnexus.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm)...

Comment: Cheap option use OutputDebugString + dbmon.exe from the sdk/sysinternals debugview

Comment: debugging for you or for the end-user? (edit: I asked this because I was thinking of `OutputDebugString` Alex just mentioned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches.

1. You can continue to link your application as a windowed application, and use `AllocConsole` to create a console window in which you can output your debugging information. Note that this only opens kernel handles, so you would need to use `_open_osfhandle` and `_fdopen` to connect stdout/stderr to your console.
2. You can link your application as a console application, not forgetting that it now starts with `_tmain` instead of `_tWinMain()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is totally possible.  Write a console application and proceed with regular window registration, create a window and listen for events.  Note that using the blocking standard input on the same thread as the one with your window message loop should be avoided (window becomes unresponsive as long as the console input operation is not finished).

Note that you can still [allocate a console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from a windowed application, but I'm not sure if the standard output and standard error are bound to the console I/O buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever console application can manage windows by calling `CreateWindow` and performing a message loop like a window app.

And whatever window app (the one entering with `WinMain`) can associate a console with `AllocConsole`.

They are not so much different, after all! ;-)

Comment: Calling `AllocConsole` is the easy part; getting the standard input and output attached to the console is not :-)

Comment: And if you have a GUI app you cannot re-use a console already there from a starting process

Comment: @Kerrek: I usually open a fstream towards the "CON" file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use that for debugging purposes only, in a Visual C++ environment, why don't you use the Windows defined macro TRACE(). It well serves the purpose of debugging. It will write in the output window of Visual Studio. And it is very simple.